# MySQL Update Command for WordPress DataBase

Tags: mysql, wordpress, sql-update

I've a WordPress DB on a "POC" site (Proof of concept)
On this DB, I've some strings that are specific to this site :

- URL = poc.test.com
- Path = /home/user/sites/poc

I want to copy this DB on the prod DB where this strings change:

- URL = test.com
- Path = /home/user/public_html

How I can update all tables (users, post, post_meta, ...) with mysql update command?

*Table names may vary depending on the site*

Comment: Use the WP CLI https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/

Comment: Thank for your replay. But do you have a mysql command to do this for alternative running?

Comment: Since some data might be serialized, you can't just do a mysql command.